# Universal link not opening app even with valid files

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-universal-links, applinks

I am trying to open a app when universal link has been clicked .

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "com.stage",
                "paths": [
                    "/*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is valid AASA file verified it is presented .

In App Side I have added association domain "**applinks:.stage.com**"

My link present in gmail app on clicking of that is is not opening application instead it is opening safari browser.

Let me know what I am doing wrong here , the same code was working fine with 14.0 now my device is 14.4

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the universal link issue is I missed TEAMID to add it in AASA file .

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "TEAMID.com.stage",
                "paths": [
                    "/*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am posting answer so that no one will do this mistake thanks